# glVertexAttribPointer returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm using the OpenGL core profile, version 3.3

When I call glVertexAttribPointer I get GL_INVALID_OPERATION. I've already checked out http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml

```
struct
{
   GLuint program;

   GLint uni_texture;
   GLint att_coord;
} shader_fbo;

...

shader_fbo.att_coord = glGetAttribLocation(shader_fbo.program, "coordIn");
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);


/*shader_fbo.att_coord stores now 0*/    
/*vao stores now 1*/

...

GLfloat vertices[] = { -1.0, -1.0,
                       -1.0,  1.0,
                        1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0  };
GLubyte indices[] = { 0, 1, 2,
                      1, 2, 3  };
...

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader_fbo.att_coord);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader_fbo.att_coord,
                      2,
                      GL_FLOAT,
                      GL_FALSE,
                      0,
                      vertices);

...

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
```

And here comes my vertex shader

```
#version 330
in vec2 coordIn;
out vec2 coordFS;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(coordIn, 0.0, 1.0);
    coordFS = (1.0+coordIn)/2.0;
}
```

It compiles and links without any errors.

**Update:** glVertexAttribPointer works now but I get a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error when I call glDrawElements. The code is updated.

Comment: you're getting a memory error because you haven't bound any data with glBufferData()

Comment: glBufferData binds the data to the currently bound buffer(here is that "vbo") glVertexAttribPointer tells opengl how that data is packed out and how to access it in the shaders. read this for more info : http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if zero is bound to the
>   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffer object binding point and the pointer argument
>   is not NULL.

You don't seem to have bound the buffer object. *glVertexAttribArray* associates the most recently buffer object with the specified vertex attribute.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I thought that the vertex array object would replace the vertex buffer object. But now I get GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error when I call glDrawElements

Comment: You need to create a buffer object for the indices and bind it and fill it with data. Also, please accept the answer if it helps. :)